# Relaitve Velocity Obstacles

Tags: movement, collision-prediction

I am reading `Reciprocal Velocity Obstacles for Real-Time, Multi-Agent navigation` and I have trouble to understand the main part of the paper:

[image]

Let's take an example, I have 2 objects A and B. A is at (0,1) and
B is at (1, 0). A moves right 1 cell per tick, B moves down 1 per tick: which means at the next tick, they will collide (in my reference, X grows right, Y grows down).

Now, my understanding of the above paragraph:

```
PositionA = (0, 1)
PositionB = (1, 0)
VelocityA = (1, 0)
VelocityB = (0, 1)
VelocityNegativeA = (-1, 0)
VelocityNegativeB = (0, -1)
RelativeVelocity  = (1, -1)

B⊕-A = {(-1,  1)}
A⊕-B = {( 1, -1)}
# Ray Starting at A/B, heading to RelativeVelocity
RayAtA_t+1 = (0, 1) + (1, -1) = (1,  0)
RayAtB_t+1 = (1, 0) + (1, -1) = (2, -1)
```

Clearly two objects should collide, but none of these rays at t+1 does intersect the set `{(-1, 1)}` ? Sorry for being obtuse but I don't understand what authors mean